# Which songs on the Star Wars soundtracks have vocals?

Tags: star-wars, music

I was watching an episode of *The Simpsons* in which Bart and Skinner battle to the tune of Obi-Wan and Anakin's fight on Mustafar from *Revenge of the Sith*.

It reminded me of a question I've pondered before, regarding vocals on the soundtracks and scores of the *Star Wars* trilogies.

Aside from the song above, the only *Star Wars* songs I can think of that have vocal parts are [Yub Nub](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=np6vAuS0KNs), various [other](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wmdEg3T8IOM) Ewok [chants](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wk6aOn_OVWI), and the [horrid cartoonish jazz singers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PiDRgDmXGi4) in the revised version of *Return of the Jedi*.  Am I missing anything?

### Which songs heard in the *Star Wars* films have vocal elements?

Comment: I wanted to link to Bill Murray "singing" the Star Wars "theme "on _Saturday Night Live_ but NBC blocked it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Music from the Star Wars films with vocals:

### I - The Phantom Menace

- [Duel of the Fates](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTg6hg1miFg) - Epic choral music during the duel between, Obi-Wan, Qui-Gon, and Darth Maul on Naboo. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_Star_Wars#First_appearance_in_Episode_I:_The_Phantom_Menace):

  > Featuring choral interjections derived from the archaic Celtic poem "Cad Goddeu" ("Battle of the Trees") translated into Sanskrit, the theme is used to represent the clash between the Light Side and the Dark Side. In English, the text reads: "Under the tongue root a fight most dread, and another raging behind, in the head."
- [Duel of the Fates-related chanting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSXCR1Q_e4Q&t=2m) - This idea is heard at several other moments throughout the film.
- [Jar Jar's Introduction and The Swim to Otoh Gunga](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ymbJEJrBzo&t=1m24s) - A sweeping, eerie female choir for the underwater city.
- [The Droid Invasion and The Appearance of Darth Maul](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ts0b3jtCOho&t=3m25s) - The Emperor's Theme is heard often throughout the films.
- [The High Council Meeting and Qui-Gon's Funeral](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pefoJcg6JzQ&t=2m1s) - A male chorus sings a sort of theme of mourning.
- [Augie's Great Municipal Band and End Credits](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7hj6qP167k) - A children's choir performs a sped-up, optimistic version of the Emperor's Theme.
- <sub>Source music<sup>1</sup>: [The Street Singer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWCy97s55fE) - An awkward, painful wailing that is, thankfully, barely audible in the film when Qui-Gon and Watto meet after the race.</sub>

### II - Attack of the Clones

- [Yoda And The Younglings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pznIg1X0rLQ&t=2m3s) - A soft, heavenly choir performs as Kenobi and Yoda examine the holographic star map.
- [Return to Tatooine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSjxlku624g&t=3m36s) - Duel of the Fates is reprised when Anakin sets out to find his mother.
- [The Tusken Camp and The Homestead](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tSWXn9ALQMI&t=5m16s) - A low male chorus sings as Anakin returns with his mother's body.
- [Confrontation with Count Dooku and Finale](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLlS8i3sFWs) - Female vocals capture the eeriness and mystery as Tyranus escapes and meets up with Sidious.

### III - Revenge of the Sith

- [Battle of the Heroes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixjd_GvNRu8&t=3m54s) and [Anakin vs. Obi-Wan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tl-dmo9_VCg) - An epic, yet tragic choral theme for the battle between Vader and Kenobi.
- [Anakin's Betrayal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m2p-im7cxa4) - A mournful choir laments the deaths of the Jedi during Order 66.
- [Grievous Speaks to Lord Sidious](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEziFftEg20) - A choral fanfare for Grievous' arrival on Utapau.
- [Palpatine's Teachings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PaCaMxN4yGE) - Eerie, low male chorus sings during the opera scene.
- [Padmé's Ruminations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tO_nHt1qA-A) - Synth female vocals wail eerily as Anakin decides which path to follow.
- [Anakin's Dark Deeds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJJZunXbSIU) - Dramatic choir fanfare as Vader takes out the separatist leaders and Palpatine creates the Galactic Empire.
- [The Birth of the Twins and Padmé's Destiny](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32aROg_EYLc&t=1m36s) - The theme of mourning from *Episode I* returns for Padme's funeral and as Vader's robotic suit is assembled.
- Duel of the Fates returns in the [unreleased music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkPtEbwmBXc) from the duels between Yoda and Palpatine / Obi-Wan and Anakin.

### Solo

- [Enfys Nest theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8N5Lzq-F0qk) - an especially unusual choral theme for the marauders and Enfys Nest, heard [throughout the score](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vax5y2ktgEw).
- [L3 & Millenium Falcon](https://youtu.be/VjUSbnToPY0?t=98) - the Star Wars main theme gets a choir for an added sense of awe.
- Duel of the Fates is reprised in [this unreleased cue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPC5ur9wQak) as Maul and Qi'ra conspire.
- <sub>Source music: [Chicken in the Pot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8QvoUr2HphE) - heard in Dryden Vos' club.</sub>

### Rogue One

- [Guardians of the Whills Suite](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LqcXAPejbj0) - A heavenly [chorus](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/147565/are-there-actual-lyrics-connected-to-portions-of-the-guardians-of-the-whills-s) gives Chirrut Imwe's music its gravitas (Heard again on album in [The Master Switch](https://youtu.be/_bglf5NuXWI?t=2m18s)).
- [Your Father Would Be Proud](https://youtu.be/Qemb3iBlp1o?t=1m40s) - Poignant strings and choir, joined later by Jyn's Theme, drive the emotion of the heroes' sacrifice.
- [Hope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RaEzKRngCyY) - An epic choral variation of the Imperial March during Darth Vader's rampage.

### IV - A New Hope

- <sub>None of the music from *Episode IV* has any vocal elements.</sub>

### V - The Empire Strikes Back

- [Imperial Starfleet Deployed/City in the Clouds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmovqqHTqZ4&t=4m37s) - A high, deceptively beautiful female choir performs a sort of siren's song as the Falcon flies towards Cloud City, a supposedly safe place to hide.

### VI - Return of the Jedi

- [The Emperor Arrives / The Death of Yoda / Obi-Wan's Revelation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvnPabT9SAg&t=1m4s), [Shuttle Tydirium Approaches Endor](https://youtu.be/DcS9Uvb56sI?t=37), [Emperor's Throne Room](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8H26Hdv3i0U&t=1m), [The Battle of Endor II](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIl0H2yF3aY&t=1m1s) - An eerie, mysterious low male chorus performs the Emperor's theme and is played in several scenes (and in several films).
- [The Battle of Endor II](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIl0H2yF3aY&t=5m) - A tragic, emotional chorus crescendos as Luke goes on the offensive.
- [Victory Celebration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=II04E2GEJG8) - A children's choir and then full choir celebrate the Rebel victory.
- [Ewok Celebration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G145Wyzg4ms) - A tribal choir rejoices in the demise of the Empire.
- <sub>Source music: [Lapti Nek](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLjFjp8Fm6U&feature=iv&src_vid=dV0LD-QAzg0&annotation_id=annotation_676175) - performed in Jabba's Palace.</sub>
- <sub>Source music: [Jedi Rocks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PiDRgDmXGi4) - the [Honeycomb guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9DZ-8Uv3Z0) introduces a song that I pretend doesn't exist in any universe.</sub>

### VII - The Force Awakens

- [Snoke](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mSQ3BJVMfAI) - Sinister, menacing male chorus sings a deep and threatening theme for the Supreme Leader.
- <sub>Source music: [Jabba Flow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-eVfuzJcf8c) and [Dobra Doompa](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UdAD9VZta3o) are performed in Maz Kanata's Castle.</sub>

### VIII - The Last Jedi

- [Revisiting Snoke](https://youtu.be/xrLBaE5QWUQ?t=8s) and [A New Alliance](https://youtu.be/ibEIp2mmU0c?t=10s)- The deep male chorus returns to reprise Snoke's music.
- [The Supremacy](https://youtu.be/qnQ779i3fDg?t=2m32s) - Soft, subtle vocals accompany Leia's theme.
- [The Battle of Crait](https://youtu.be/YIIvAoHIsPQ?t=6m6s) - An enormously emotional chorus accompanies Finn’s charge towards the First Order.
- [The Last Jedi](https://youtu.be/U9e5JcKxHaA?t=51s) - A powerful chorus adds gravity throughout the film's climax (including heightening the intensity of [Kylo Ren's theme](https://youtu.be/U9e5JcKxHaA?t=1m50s)).

### IX - The Rise of Skywalker

- [Anthem of Evil](https://youtu.be/YKtn8GXL_g8) - An eerie low choir shows the influence and temptation of the Dark Side.
- [Final Saber Duel](https://youtu.be/NVrQzCXlhFM?t=196) - There seems to be a subtle touch of a heavenly chorus when Leia reaches out through the Force.
- [Approaching the Throne](https://youtu.be/zvNVKNiLTtY?t=234) - Evil, declamatory chanting cries out as we reach the Emperor's throne on Exegol.
- [The Force is with You](https://youtu.be/qZJFjmLhQw4) - Soft, melancholy vocals show the hopelessness of the battle and the sinister, ominous choir of Palpatine's theme crescendos as he is defeated.
- [Farewell](https://youtu.be/zBy3bnSyi6w?t=259) - Heavenly voices celebrate the victory of the Resistance across the galaxy.

---

<sub>1. [Source music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_music) refers to music in a drama (e.g., film or video game) that is part of the fictional setting and so, presumably, is heard by the characters. It can be background music (e.g., from a radio or TV) or be produced by characters themselves as part of the plot</sub>

Comment: I forgot the humming in Emperor's theme.  D'oh.

Comment: I said **I** did.  It's very subtle, unlike the Obi-Wan/Anakin song.

Comment: Is the Emperor's theme the same music that is played when Luke is defeating Vader? Because that has chorus in it as well.

Comment: I removed the "in order of release" so your answer doesn't have to be edited.  Excellent work, many thanks, and +1.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is vocal music in Solo?  Like when Enfys Nest's crew swoops in during the heist on Vandor?