# Which soundtrack edition contains the bar songs from Maz's castle?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, music

I just bought the Original Soundtrack for *The Force Awakens* and much to my disappointment and disgust it does not include the tracks "Jabba Flow" and "Dobra Doompa" from Maz's castle.

I checked with the prior SEQ (*) [on soundtracks with vocals](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116483/which-songs-on-the-star-wars-soundtracks-have-vocals), then with [the list of additional music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_%28soundtrack%29#Additional_music), but it indeed looks like, unlike the ANH soundtrack which featured the Mos Eisley bar song, TFA's soundtrack doesn't.

Or did I buy the wrong edition/version?

(*) Stack Exchange Question - surely that's a standard acronym by now? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A remix of *Jabba Flow* is available on the album *[Star Wars Headspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Headspace)*.

Unfortunately, neither the original version of the song nor *Dobra Doompa* seem to be available at the moment.

**Edit:** The original version of *Jabba Flow* is now available on [iTunes](http://www.starwars.com/news/star-wars-day-surprise-hear-the-full-version-of-jabba-flow-from-the-force-awakens) and [Spotify](https://open.spotify.com/track/0UO2Vjeo0H3LB9eVeOUmOf), as a single.

Comment: Trippy! Though admittedly I can't recognise a bit from the movie.

Comment: Downloaded! I don't know why but this song makes me happy! :D Going to running around all day with it stuck in my head.

Comment: Oh, and happy May 4th everybody, all those who are behind us antepodeans!