# Are there actual lyrics connected to portions of the “Guardians of the Whills” suite?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

here is a part of the score of the film that has a choir singing: It seems to be a true lyric and not just a vocalization humming or “ooohhhHHH / aahhhHHH” type vocalization.

On the released soundtrack, this piece is titled the [“Guardian of the Whills Suite.”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LqcXAPejbj0) Is there any information as to what might be sung?

I only have the digital copy so if it is in the liner notes, those are unavailable to me at the moment.